# JDBC programming

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

I am working in command prompt this is my code

```
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.sql.Statement;
public class JDBC {

    static {

        try {

            Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException cnf) {
            System.out.println("Driver could not be loaded: " + cnf);
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        String connectionUrl = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/mysql";
        String dbUser = "root";
        String dbPwd = "admin";
        Connection conn;
        ResultSet rs;
        String queryString = "SELECT ID, NAME FROM exptable";

        try {
            conn = DriverManager.getConnection(connectionUrl, dbUser, dbPwd);
            Statement stmt = conn.createStatement();

            // INSERT A RECORD
            stmt.executeUpdate("INSERT INTO exptable (name) VALUES (\"TINU K\")");

            // SELECT ALL RECORDS FROM EXPTABLE
            rs = stmt.executeQuery(queryString);

            System.out.println("ID \tNAME");
            System.out.println("============");
            while (rs.next()) {
                System.out.print(rs.getInt("id") + ".\t" + rs.getString("name"));
                System.out.println();
            }
            if (conn != null) {
                conn.close();
                conn = null;
            }
        } catch (SQLException sqle) {
            System.out.println("SQL Exception thrown: " + sqle);
        }
    }
}
```

i am getting error like 
`java.lang.ClassNotFoundException` and `java.sql.SQLException` 
so may i know what mistake have i made

Comment: can you post the stack trace

Comment: First exception Looks like you miss the mysql-connector in classpath

Comment: i have added mysql-connector-java-5.1.13-bin in classpath but still i have the error

Comment: Didn't you get any error while compiling?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might have missed the classpath in your java command. While executing from command prompt you must mention the class path along with your command.

java -cp

```
ex:
java -cp /home/test/jars:/home/test/src com.test.Lab
```